# HTML table scrollbar issue

Tags: html, css

In the following code I tried to make a long table scrollable ( with `<thead>` fixed ).

But the columns are not filling the table's width anymore, and `thead` columns are even not aligned with `tbody`s ones.

How to solve this ? is there another way to do the trick.

The code [is here](http://jsfiddle.net/riless/fr3gqbqh/)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ROW 01</th>
            <th>ROW 02</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>LINE 01</td><td><img src="http://placehold.it/90x90"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>LINE 02</td><td><img src="http://placehold.it/90x90"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>LINE 03</td><td><img src="http://placehold.it/90x90"/></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS here

```
table{width: 100%; background: #efefef; border-collapse: collapse }
thead, tbody{display: block}
thead{background: #555; color: white;}
tbody{height: 120px; overflow: auto}
td, th{ border: 1px solid red; }
```

Comment: can you give your `td` & `th` a fixed width? (i.e. `width: 100px;` or 50%)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fr3gqbqh/4/

Comment: Remove `thead, tbody{display: block}`  http://jsfiddle.net/fr3gqbqh/6/

Comment: @blurfus it will be my last solution

Comment: @Paramasivan The table will not be scrollable without that

Comment: Make as 2 tables with similar css; one for head and the another will be body ; fix height for the second table.

Comment: Try this one [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/fozepemagupu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to turn your `<tr>` in `display:table;`+`table-layout:fixed;` It will help but columns may break from a row to another [unless you set a fixed width to one](http://jsfiddle.net/fr3gqbqh/12/) or the other cell.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fr3gqbqh/10/)**

Your CSS turns like:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    background: #efefef;
    border-collapse: collapse
}
thead, tbody {
    display: block
}
thead {
    background: #555;
    color: white;
    padding-right:1em;/* average width of the scroll bar of tbody */
}
tbody {
    height: 120px;
    overflow: auto
}
tr {/* here make those the table */
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
td, th {/* set a width to go along with table-layout */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: box-sizing:border-box; will include borders into specified width : http://jsfiddle.net/fr3gqbqh/11/

Comment: yes, seems to be a good solution, but the horizontal borders are not collapsed

Comment: you can fix it removing border-top in tbody tbody tr td {border-top:none;} http://jsfiddle.net/fr3gqbqh/16/

Answer (score 1):

add this to your CSS

`td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) { min-width: 200px; } /* or the width you need, you may use percentages */
td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2) { min-width: 200px; }`

since the browser adds a scrollbar, it needs to add the space for that element, thus, the misalignment will ALWAYS happen. The good news is that, in fact, you need to declare only the first column, so if you plan to use only 1 columns, just use something like this:

```
td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) { width:20%; min-width: 200px; }
```

and it will be enough.

There's no way that I know to do this without declaring the width for AT LEAST the first column

Answer (score -1):

try

```
thead, tbody{display:auto}
```